# Vue - Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js.

I cloned a project from github and i tried to run it by `npm run dev`.
Unfortunately it gives me this kind of error

```
> webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --env.dev

 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
   throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\123\Desktop\python2020\Eduwonka\element-starter\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:54:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! element-starter@ dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --env.dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the element-starter@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-19T15_05_27_959Z-debug.log
```

Like i said before, I'm new to Vue and I have no idea where to start look for.
Anyone can please direct me what should i do? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution `npm install --save-dev webpack` - I dont know why, but it worked